# Forgot password not sending email

Tags: magento, magento-1.5

Wonder if you can help me. I have a Magento installation and when a customer selects "forgot password" the system does NOT send the reset password email.

All the other emails are working fine. I have setup the New Password template and assigned it in the admin of Magento.

I can't for the life of me figure out why only the Reset password emails are not sending and the others are.

Please help.

Thanks,
Ev

Comment: Yes, there is nothing in there.

Answer (score 1):

To solve the issue it is enough to delete the custom customer.xml used by your theme in app/design/frontend///layout/, so default layout shipped with base theme (in app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/customer.xml) will be used.

Or the custom customer.xml can be updated to include the following section:

```
<customer_account_resetpassword translate="label">
    <label>Reset a Password</label>
    <remove name="right"/>
    <remove name="left"/>

    <reference name="head">
        <action method="setTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
        <action method="setHeaderTitle" translate="title" module="customer">
            <title>Reset a Password</title>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="customer/account_resetpassword" name="resetPassword" template="customer/form/resetforgottenpassword.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</customer_account_resetpassword>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the `app/code/core/Mage/Customer/controllers/AccountController.php` file. Look for `forgotPasswordPostAction`. Analyze it step by step - check if `$this->getRequest()->getParams()` provides you the emal addresss, check if it validates (maybe some local changes have been made to the validation code). Look at the password generation code - is the new passsword generated? Check out the `Mage_Customer_Model_Customer` class and the `sendPasswordReminderEmail` method and try to track the bug in there. Print all the values you can get there (email, names, store configs and check for exceptions and warnings - turn php error displaying!).

This should help you tracking down the problem, and gather enough data to identify it.

Comment: Thanks, going to do that now. Will revert

Comment: All the variables are showing. Name, email, storeid, new password. Can't find the bug and all the code is stock standard Magento.