# magento forgot password email not sending

Tags: magento

I'm using magento 1.7.2.but facing a problem with email sending. when customer request for a new password with forgot password form,they don't got any email.but message "If there is an account associated with arif04cuet2@gmail.com you will receive an email with a link to reset your password." is showing.

i found similar questions here but not working for me.
[Forgot password not sending email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8923150/forgot-password-not-sending-email)
[Magento not sending forgot password emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9192427/magento-not-sending-forgot-password-emails)
i am using custom template.

can any one help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

First step would be to switch to the default Magento template, then see if the password reset emails are working.  If they do, then it's most likely an issue specific to your template.

If it still doesn't work, it could be an issue with the local email server settings itself.

For emailing issues, I would recommend installing SMTP Pro by ASchroder.

https://github.com/aschroder/Magento-SMTP-Pro-Email-Extension

After installing:

1. go to `System > Configuration > System (under Advanced)`
2. Open `SMTP Pro Email General Settings`
3. For `Choose extension option` select `SMTP`
4. Set `Log all messages` to `Yes`
5. Expand the `SMTP Pro Email SMTP Settings` section
6. Set `Authentication to None` and leave `Username` and `Password` blank (this is assuming the apache user your Magento is running on is allowed to send emails through SMTP.  If not, you should enter in the correct SMTP login settings for this area.
7. Set `Host` to `localhost` and `Port` to `25`
8. Save your configuration, and then click `Run Self Test` under the `SMTP Pro Email General Settings` section.

If the test was successful, password reset emails should now be working.  If the user did not receive the email, it may of either been blocked by their incoming mail server, or filtered into their spam folder.  If you have access to your server's mail logs, you can see if the emails being sent from Magento are being accepted by the mail servers they are being sent to.

You can view a log of emails being sent from Magento under `System > Tools > Email Log` after this extension is enabled and `Log All Messages` is set to yes in the configuration.

Comment: i saw that SMTP Pro by ASchroder is not Compatible with 1.7

Comment: Had the same issue described above. The SMTP Pro Extension worked for me (magento 1.7.2).

Comment: Just a note: Forgotten reminders only send to registered accounts. It's silly, though you may miss the fact that your test e-mail address which you use always is not registered as a customer on Magento, and so it won't accuse anything in logs, neither you will receive mail, because the e-mail was not registered.

Comment: @Axel My issue, password reset mail working but it takes a long time to the sent customer, once customer received its shows, reset password link expired. How can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Magento 1.9 not sending emails when customer request for a new password with forgot password form,they don't got any email.

I fix to this problem is actually very simple way

Admin  System > Configuration > Advanced > System > Mail sending settings > Set return path > YES

I Hope Work well